# creating a array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

is this:

`var arr = {};`

the same as

`var arr = new Array();`

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not the same.

```
var arr = {};
```

initializes an object. If you want an array:

```
var arr = [];
```

Comment: Just to complete the answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 4):

not exactly. `var arr = [];` is more like it.

Answer (score 2):

No.

```
var arr = {}; // creates a new object with no properties
```

But

```
var arr = []; // creates a new blank array
```

Answer (score 1):

`var arr = {};` creates object

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not: You're confusing [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Array_Literals)

```
var arr = []; // same as new Array()
```

with [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals)

```
var obj = {}; // same as new Object()
```